# How do i get each byte into a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, byte, midi

I want to open a MIDI file and analyse each byte. But i am VERY unfamiliar with handeling bytes and bits. Midi's are written in hexadecimal if that does any difference.

What i want to do is put each byte into a list, and then make a for loop to check each one. How would i go about doing that?

I've come this far (which isn't very far):

```
# Open MIDI file
mFile = open("test.mid", 'rb')

# Checks if file is MIDI
hChunk = mFile.read(4)
if hChunk != b'MThd':
    raise ValueError('Not a MIDI file')

print(mFile.read())
```

Also if anyone has any easy to understand MIDI format explanation links, that would be appreciated! :)

Comment: `contents =  mFile.read()`. `contents` is now an array of bytes, that you can access with `contents[n]` n being the offset. It will give you the value of the bytes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean by "the value of the byte"? When i print contents i get _b'MThd\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00_ (etc) and if i take fx contents[0] i get 77. What does the 77 represent? And how do i get it in the xFF format? Thanks!

Comment: 77 is the ASCII value of "M". If you need byte sequences instead of numbers then slice instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just completed your code to scan the first 40 bytes of data. It prints the decimal value as well as the hex value using both C-like `%` formatting and more pythonic `format` method, which may be more understandable if format specification is in hex.

midi file has been downloaded [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIDI_sample.mid?qsrc=3044) and saved in the directory of the script (hence the strange `__file__` stuff to compute proper dir when testing)

```
import os

# Open MIDI file
mFile = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"MIDI_sample.mid"), 'rb')

# Checks if file is MIDI
hChunk = mFile.read(4)
if hChunk != b'MThd':
    raise ValueError('Not a MIDI file')

contents = mFile.read()
mFile.close()

total_len = len(contents)

for i in range(0,40):
    print(contents[i],"x%02X"% contents[i],"x{:02X}".format(contents[i]))
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! I have one last question though; what does the line "x%02X"% contents[i] do / how does it work? Does it just change the 77 to a hex value?

Comment: it converts the value to an hexadecimal string, only for display/debug purposes. To compare integers with given values you can just do : `contents[i]==0x4d`

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help!